# Delete row from multiple table in html file on the basis of condition using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Need help from you.
I have an HTML file on a Linux machine and I want to delete a row if 'no' is there in any row of these tables.

The HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Checking files</title>
  </head>
  <body>              
    <h1>Table 1</h1>
      <p>
        Checking data of yes or no
      </p>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7" style="text-align:center"><h2 class="heading">Data 1</h2></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th style="width:33%">Names</th>
        <td>Serial</th>
            <th>Severe?</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Remark Date</th>
          </tr>

                                                
            <tr class="checks-one">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Net_one</td>
              <td>int</td>
              <td>yes</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>action</td>
            </tr>
                                                
            <tr class="check-two">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Name_two</td>
              <td>hex</td>
              <td>no</td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>no action</td>
            </tr>
                                                
            <tr class="check-three">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Name_three</td>
              <td>hex</td>
              <td>yes</td>
              <td>58</td>
              <td>action</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            
      <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7" style="text-align:center"><h2 class="cert-kind">Data 2</h2></th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th style="width:33%">Names</th>
        <td>Serial</th>
            <th>Severe?</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Remark Date</th>
          </tr>

                                                
            <tr class="checks-one">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Net_one</td>
              <td>int</td>
              <td>yes</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>action</td>
            </tr>
                                                
            <tr class="check-two">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Name_two</td>
              <td>hex</td>
              <td>no</td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>no action</td>
            </tr>
                                                
            <tr class="check-three">
              <td style="text-align:center"><i class="alert"></i></td>
              <td style="width:33%">Name_three</td>
              <td>hex</td>
              <td>yes</td>
              <td>58</td>
              <td>action</td>
            </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output of this html file is mentioned below

```
Table 1
Checking data of yes or no

Data 1
    Names   Serial  Severe? Days    Remark Date
Net_one     int yes 50  action
Name_two    hex no  55  no action
Name_three  hex yes 58  action
Data 2
    Names   Serial  Severe? Days    Remark Date
Net_one     int yes 50  action
Name_two    hex no  55  no action
Name_three  hex yes 58  action
```

my expected output is:

```
Table 1
Checking data of yes or no

Data 1
    Names   Serial  Severe? Days    Remark Date
Net_one     int yes 50  action
Name_three  hex yes 58  action
Data 2
    Names   Serial  Severe? Days    Remark Date
Net_one     int yes 50  action
Name_three  hex yes 58  action
```

I am new in shell scripting, I tried multiple ways with awk, sed but none of them is working. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for help to modify your HTML file so please show the expected output as the updated HTML file, not some text that would be present in some display from some tool interpreting the HTML file afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
awk -v RS="</tr>" '
    !/<td>no<\/td>/{ a=(NR==1 ? "" : a RS) $0 }
    END{ print a }
' file.html
```

With your exact example, this GNU awk seems to do the trick.

- set row separator to `</tr>`
- add all "rows" that do not contain a field with "no" to a variable (just don't prepend with the field separator on the first "row")
- print out the recreated html file

Try it out, see if it works for you.

---

Edit: First thing that came to mind was work with a variable, but that can easily be removed and the result would be this:

```bsh
awk -v RS="</tr>" -v ORS="" '!/<td>no<\/td>/{ print (NR==1 ? "" : RS) $0 }' file.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kaffe, you help me a lot